# Fixed searchbar like contacts

Tags: ios7, uisearchbar, searchbar

http://s7.postimg.org/suz457l23/IMG_0092.png

I want to use a UISearchBar that doesn't move, like in Apple's Contacts app. I also want to these components at the same depth, and I don't want the search bar in the tableview header.

- UINavigationBar
- UISearchBar
- UITableView

When I try to attach UISearchBar below UINavigationBar in storyboard, interface builder doesn't show me suitable guideline. The guideline only generates when in tableview.

Is there no way to attach the search bar below UINavigationBar without programming?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also searching an elegant way to build the search bar..

What I have now is a `UINavigationController`, inside which I have a `UIViewController`.

This `UIViewController` contains `UISearchBar` and `UITableView`. You can program the search bar on top and tableView below it.

vborra's link also helps.

Answer (score -1):

It is easy to do what you are looking for, `UISearchBar` is somewhat meant for this. See the tutorial Here: http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/